# How to solve database error like database and cursor not close properly

Tags: android

hi all members thanks in advance.

when i run my Database application in logcat show the error like:

database and cursor not close properly

application is not crash but sometime it creates a problem in device
how can i get rid of this error?
it always happen when i run any database application.

Comment: Do you close the database or leave it open and how do you manage your cursor, startManagingCursor(cursor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the cursor if exists after your code execution done (in `finally` statements)

```
finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

always close the cursor using `cursor.close()`